# How to pass JSON array correctly?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

i am trying to create a fade effect with the following...ive been told im nearly there apart from the passing of the json array.  At the moment no images are displayed.

```
 //generate all the boxes
$.get('images.php',function(data){
  for (var i=0; i < totalBoxes; i++){
      var randomImage = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
      $('<div class="pf-box"><img class="black" src="' + randomImage['black'] + '" /><img class="colour" src="' + randomImage['colour'] + '" /></div>').hide().appendTo('#bg').fadeIn('slow').filter('.colour').css("opacity", 0);
  }
 },'json');

 //add the hover behavior to all the elements
 $('.colour').hover(function() {
   $(this).stop().fadeTo(700, 1);
 },function() {
   $(this).stop().fadeTo(700, 0);
 });
```

and images.php

```
    <?php 
   header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '[  
    {'black' : 'images/random/1.jpg', 'colour' : 'images/random/1-c.jpg'},  
    {'black' : 'images/random/2.jpg', 'colour' : 'images/random/2-c.jpg'}
]';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use randomImage.black instead of randomImage['black']

Comment: there's no difference between the two in JavaScript

Comment: there is no official support for associative arrays in JavaScript.. give those points back

Comment: no problem, I forgot the "!" telling that I wasn't really mad.. :) here's a reference: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

Comment: "i didnt know i had removed any points sorry" Don't bother, I think it's Mr. Haboustak

Comment: No probs Mike i appreciate your help...do you know how i could get teh hover working?

Comment: if you do a alert(randomImage) in your loop, you have anything?

Comment: comes up with a load of [object object]

Comment: the transparent image should then fade in

Comment: 'randomImage' in the code above isn't an array, it's an object (see the JSON). The variable 'data' is the array and that array is being indexed with a numeric index. 

So randomImage['black'] here is just fine (and quite common to leverage the language's dynamic nature).

Comment: Sorry i am out of my depoth here...do you know why it isnt hovering?

Comment: You're only applying the hover to the colour images: $('img', $('#bg'))

Comment: i changed .colour to your $('img', $('#bg'))  and it made no difference ;(

Comment: If you remove all the animation and only append a visible image... maybe we look at the wrong part of the problem?

Comment: remove everything after the appendTo and remove the hide()

Comment: @Mike: Back to your answer: What do you want to tell us? In standard ECMAScript randomImage.black === randomImage['black'], so what?

Comment: @Boldewyn: It wasn't an answer, it was a comment. And the point of the comment was that the original code change suggested by this answer is inconsequential. The two options are synonyms and both are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need to escape the quotes inside the JSON string?  Otherwise the php interpreter will fail to send all of what you want, and may even barf out some errors.

Comment: I am trying to create this effect: 
http://www.yellostudio.co.uk/temp/index.php 

with the code above on 
http://www.yellostudio.co.uk/temp/indexV2.php

Do you know where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your echo is failing because of the single quotes in the JSON output breaking out of the echo.

Enclose your string with different quotes so you can echo properly:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json'); 
echo "[
    {'black' : 'images/random/1.jpg', 'colour' : 'images/random/1-c.jpg'},
    {'black' : 'images/random/2.jpg', 'colour' : 'images/random/2-c.jpg'} 
]"; 
?>
```

Note the use of double quotes to enclose the echo string, instead of the single quotes you've used. (if you had double quotes inside the string, then you'd reverse it and use single on the outside).